r.in.xyz (GRASS GIS) not outputting a raster
I have a xyz file points from a lidar dataset and I want to create a raster from it. I'm trying to use r.in.xyz to import it and it seems to be working and it founds 1641751 points, no errors or messages, but when the process ends there is nothing in my mapset.
I'm on GRASS GIS 8.2.1

Just to update, if I launched from the command prompt it seems it is stopping at 78% when "Writing to output raster map...", but it does not show any error message

It may not be the source of the problem in this case, but make sure your computational region is correct: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.in.xyz.html#setting-region-bounds-and-resolution

The region is correct, I double checked because I saw that someone had an issue with that
